# Regex pattern issue remove specific digits

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to use a regex to extract a time string in this format only "01 Apr 2022". But I'm having trouble getting these digits out "07:28:00".

```cpp
std::string test = "Fri, 01 Apr 2022 07:28:00 GMT";

std::string get_date(std::string str) {
    static std::vector<std::regex> patterns = {
        std::regex{"Fri,(.+)([0-9]+)GMT"},
    };

    for (auto& regex : patterns) {
        std::smatch m;
        if (std::regex_search(str, m, regex)) {
            return m[1]; 
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a regex which will do the job: `std::regex reg{R"(\d{2} \w+ \d{4})"};`. And in your code you use `m[0]`, not `m[1]`.

---

But if your format is stable (and it sure looks like one) you don't need regex at all. Just do something like this: `str.substr(5, 12)` or `std::string(str.begin() + 5, str.begin() + 16)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would (strongly) advise against using a regex for this purpose.

The C++ standard library already has an `std::get_time` to handle tasks like this, and I'd advise simply using it. In this case, the format you've shown seems to fit with a `get_time` format string like: `"%a, %d %b %Y %T"`.

Demo code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>

std::string test = "Fri, 01 Apr 2022 07:28:00 GMT";

int main() {
    std::istringstream buffer { test };

    std::tm t;

    buffer >> std::get_time(&t, "%a, %d %b %Y %T");

    std::cout << "Hour: " << t.tm_hour 
              << ", Minute: " << t.tm_min
              << ", Second: " << t.tm_sec << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```cpp
std::regex{R"(^[a-zA-Z]{3},\s*(.*?)\s*\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2})"}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QC4EEo/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]{3}` - three letters
- `,` - a comma
  -`\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s*`
- `\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2}` - two digits, `:`, two digits, `:` and two digits.

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/lnSetH):

```cpp
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


std::string get_date(std::string str) {
        static std::vector<std::regex> patterns = {
            std::regex{R"(^[a-zA-Z]{3},\s*(.*?)\s*\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2})"},
        };
        
        for (auto& regex : patterns) {
            std::smatch m;
            if (std::regex_search(str, m, regex)) {
                return m[1]; 
            }
        }
        return str;
}
        
int main() {
    std::cout << get_date("Fri, 01 Apr 2022 07:28:00 GMT") << std::endl;    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
01 Apr 2022
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give the pattern like this -

```
"(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun),\s+(\d{1,})\s+(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Nov|Dec)\s+(\d{4})\s+(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+GMT"
```

Then the 5th group `m[4]` should give you the time (hh:mm:ss) part